# How to simply replace android AsyncTask with RX / Coroutines and return a value?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rx-java2, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

this method runs a database operation (returns a generated ID) and must be on background thread:

`fun insert(note: Note): Long{
    return noteDao.insert(note)
}`

Is there a way to implement it using RX / Coroutines? (without using the `suspend` keyword)

I currently use AsyncTask:

```
override fun insert(note: Note): Long {
    return InsertTask(this, noteDao).execute(note).get()
}
```

`private class InsertTask(noteRepository: NoteRepository, private val noteDao: NoteDao) : AsyncTask<Note, Void, Long>() {`

```
    override fun doInBackground(vararg note: Note): Long {
        return noteDao.insert(note[0])
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(generatedId: Long) {
        getTheId(generatedId)
    }

    private fun getTheId( id: Long): Long {
        return id
    }
}
```

Comment: So should it be Rx, or coroutines?

Comment: both might be possible but I found and wrote Rx solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With coroutines, it's pretty easy. But you will need coroutines support for `Room`.

Gradle dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.1.0"
```

Next, mark your methods in dao as suspend.

```
@Insert
suspend fun insert(note: Note): Long
```

I don't know how much info you have about coroutines, but it goes like that:

```
aCoroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
 //to make analogy you are inside the do in backgroun here
  val id = dao.insert(note)
  withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
  //oh well you can call this onPostExecute :) 
  //do whatever you need with that selectId here
  handleIdOnTheMainThread(id)
  }
}
```

But I do insist not to use it with 0 information about coroutines.

About RxJava:

Room has also support for Rx, so please refer to [this link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757).

Comment: I need an example with a return value. as mentioned, I'm not interested in the `suspend` keyword, even when using it like this, I get compile errors.. the RX link looks promising :) thanks!

Comment: It works the same with a return value, where could be the difference

Comment: not possible to return a val from within the `launch` or `withContext`.

Comment: you don't need to return a value from launch or withContext, the value will be returned as simple iterative programing instructions. `val a = returnMethod()`. That's why I told you that you need to handle the basics of coroutines before using them.

Comment: `override fun insert(note: Note): Long {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val selectId  = noteDao.insert(note)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            }
        }
        return ?
    }`

Comment: No, that's not what I wrote

Comment: true :) how would you fill in this method?

Comment: First of all you don't write inside the overiden insert method, because that is handled by `Room` itself. In you `Presenter`/`ViewModel` you just take the reference of the dao and just do what I have written

Comment: I really appreciate you time, notice you wrote separate methods: insert + getid, when calling insert already gets me the id..
and what to do with - val selectId?
i think there has to be a return val for the Long id we return thru insert, thats how the auto generated ID works.

Comment: Ok , I'm updating the answer

Comment: I still need a return val, from this Repository class back to ViewModel. returning myVal does this right away, not waiting for the actual data. as I mentioned, the `suspend` doesnt compile when used like you suggested:
`override fun insert(note: Note): Long {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            myVal = noteDao.insert(note)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                handleIdOnTheMainThread(myVal)
            }
        }
        return ?
    }`

Comment: apparently you were right all along.. I simply didn't understand Coroutines enough to understand your answer, which works great :)